# Upload slideshow to Youtube

Tags: youtube

How do I upload a photo slideshow to Youtube using their API? 
I could not find it here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_uploading_videos

Looks like there is only API for regular video uploading.

**update:** 
Photo slideshow is the second option for manual video upload. Here: http://www.youtube.com/my_videos_upload

You can attach several photos, add music from predefined list and modify video settings like title, description, etc. It will be converted by Youtube to video internally and published.

Comment: YouTube is a videosite so you will probably have to convert your slideshow to a video before uploading it. What type of slideshow is it? Powerpoint?